# Adding section indicator to Metropolis theme?

Tags: beamer, themes, beamer-metropolis

I really like the Metropolis colour theme and is planning to tweak around it to make it 'mine'-ish. One thing that my supervisor is quick picky about is having some section navigation in a presentation. The good examples I can find are [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ufrn-beamer-theme/kjdfzdqywsbw#.WPMHxIgrLZs) and [another one](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/patterns-for-sos-reconfiguration/nhrgdrfjbgkj#.WPMF0IgrLZs).

Any suggestions on how I could achieve that while keeping the colour theme? (I don't even know the correct jargon for those lines, so I tried googling terms like 'section header/section navigator footer/ etc' but it was not off good help.

Comment: Do you only want to keep the Metropolis color theme or anything else too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first example you linked to, uses a modified version of the `Berlin` theme, which in return uses the headline from the `miniframe` theme. You can simply keep using the `metropolis` theme and add this headline.

What is left for you to do, is to decide which colours you want to have - just modify `\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=normal text.bg, bg=structure.fg}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=normal text.bg, bg=structure.fg}

\begin{document}

\section{section 1}
\subsection{section name}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section 3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc
\end{frame}     

\end{document}
```

[image]

[In case you prefer the navigation bar from the second template you linked to, you can have a look into `beamerouterthemesplit.sty` and take the headline from there - but personally I don't think this will look good with metropolis, as the dark frametitle is already a quite dominant element and does not need the large headline from the split theme.]

Comment: That's what I want - thanks! I agree with your point the second one would not look as good... I am trying to add the navigation circles like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292070/beamer-navigation-bar-too-long/292093)

Comment: @QuangThinhHa My solution already has these circles, if you use subsections.

Comment: Ah - thanks, I just got into this being geeky about LaTeX presentation and stuff. Just moved from Powerpoint to this wonderful world!

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for this! Is there any way to *omit* those little circles? Might prefer the look of that.

Comment: @LukeDavis yes, by using `\sectionnavigation` instead of `\insertnavigation`. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354904/36296

Comment: @samcarter For some reason your solution fails when I add options to `\documentclass{beamer}` -- for example, `\documentclass[11.5pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}`. Any idea why?

Comment: @LukeDavis Works fine for me with `\documentclass[11.5pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}`. Can you ask a new question including a MWE, the error message you get and/or a picture of the incorrect output?

Comment: It was an issue on my end, bug in this crazy compile script I use.

Comment: +1: Great! Does not work well with the package option `background = dark` though. Could I ask another question (separate follow-up) regarding this?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I'd happily answer on a Q&A site where I'm active on :)