# Making navigation using short section's title and section's first page using section's long title

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

**Currently, my document only uses a section's short title and looks like following**

[image]

**I would like to have it, however, like following**

[image]

**My doument declaration**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

%###########################################################
% Presenter's mode notes
%###########################################################
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

%###########################################################
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364904/adding-section-indicator-to-metropolis-theme
%###########################################################
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=normal text.bg, bg=structure.fg}

\begin{document}
  \section[Short text 1]{Long text 1}
  \begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \end{frame}

  \section[Short text 2]{Long text 2}
  \begin{frame}{Frame 2}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**What can I do? Thank in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metropolis theme has different options for the section page template. Unfortunately, none of them use the full section title if the short version is available.

It looks like you're using the "progressbar" option for the section page. You can find the template in `beamerinnerthememetropolis.sty`, and create a modified template that uses `\insertsection` in place of `\insertsectionhead`.

In your preamble, you might put something like:

```
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{section page}{myprogressbar}{
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{22em}
    \raggedright
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}
    \insertsection\\[-1ex]
    \usebeamertemplate*{progress bar in section page}
    \par
    \ifx\insertsubsection\@empty\else%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection title}%
      \usebeamerfont{subsection title}%
      \insertsubsection
    \fi
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  \vspace{\baselineskip}
}
\makeatother
```

Then *after* `\begin{document}`, put in:

```
\setbeamertemplate{section page}[myprogressbar]
```

That shouldn't affect the headers/footers, so it should still be the short title there if that's what you prefer.

[image: long name section page in metropolis theme]

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked!