# How to shorten the section names in the miniframe navigation bar in a Beamer?

Tags: beamer, presentations, navigation, bar

I'm having a problem with the navigation bar in a beamer. The following image shows that is overloaded with text.

[image]

In a forum I found that a way to reduce the text is to put the text in the square brackets as follows.

```
\section[IOC Implementation]{Inverse Optimal Control Implementation}
```

The problem is that i need that the section name (the grey rectangle) shows the complete name of the section, in this case "Inverse Optimal Control Implementation" and in the navigation bar the reduced text.

Is there a way where i can reduce the names in the navigation bar and in the sections still the full name?

I would appreciate the help!

**EDIT:**

The comment made by frabjous actually helped me, i had `\insertsectionhead` and i changed to `\insertsection`, that helped me to keep the long names in the sections and the contractions in the navigation bar. Also, to reduce the space in the navigation bar i used the code in [Beamer Navigation bar too long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292070/beamer-navigation-bar-too-long?rq=1).
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). We don't know what theme you're using, or how you're inserting the section titles into your document now. It might be as simple as swapping out `\insertsectionhead` with `\insertsection` in the code for inserting the section frames, but it's hard to say without knowing how you're doing it now.